# encrypt data in django that need complex search

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

we have a Django Rest app with PostgreSQL db that in some parts business force us to encrypt data.
but what I need is searching and heavy queries on data to be executed,
I've used [django-pgcrypto-fields](https://github.com/incuna/django-pgcrypto-fields) but it's not updated until 2021 and have some bugs for production,what can I do?encrypting data directly does't allow me to execute queries for search the data,also I can't find any other library to help me.

Comment: where you able to figure this out?

Comment: in the GitHub repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-cryptography package. The data will be automatically encrypted when saved to the database. It uses an encryption that allows for bi-directional data retrieval.

Comment: thanks,does it allow me to filter the encrypted data?

Comment: Mentioned package does not  filter encrypted data as far as I know. It is used for encryption and decryption only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sign package to encrypt the certain field of data

It's an inbuilt Django package so it is safe & secure also.

DB field can be charfield

```
from django.core.signing import Signer

signer = Signer()

value = signer.sign('My string') 

to decrypt just use

original = signer.unsign(value)   

can add additional security with 

signer = Signer(salt='extra')
```

Check the below link for reference

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/

Comment: I know about signing in Django but this option can't help be due I want to search the data not just encrypt and save it